BLE peripheral gets disconnected from iPhone app after a couple of hours
I currently have an app that connects to a BLE device and is able to exchange packet data, send messages to other nearby BLE devices, notify when connects/disconnects happen. The problem is when the phone gets locked and the app gets suspended/put to sleep by the system. When it is a short duration, the app gets woken up and notifies of new messages. But when a few hours have passed the device gets disconnected completely. The whole point of the app is to receive these messages regardless if the phone has been locked for like 2-4+ hours (edge case). I don't know the exact time it gets disconnected.... I am only able to conduct a test of a couple hours, or after I wake up from a night's sleep and I can't simulate this on XCode.
This app is using open source stuff, and a similar but different app is able to keep a BLE connection for way longer. This other app uses location updates permissions and mine does not. Some users have said that their background connection is reliable even if they have location set to while using app only. I ran a test and this app stays connected for longer while mine does not, even if no gps/location/or message notifications updates happen.
Can I achieve the same connection reliability without using location updates permission? What if I implement 'background refresh' of some sort or 'acts as bluetooth LE accessory'? If my app receives at least 1 notification every hour will that prevent this? I read up on Apple's "Adding Support for State Preservation and Restoration" docs, it's not well documented but do I do that? What option would you suggest?

Read this.  As soon as your app gets a disconnect from the peripheral  immediately issue a "connect".  Make sure you have set up Core Bluetooth State Restoration correctly

Okay I just implemented it, but I am still confused... I implemented a CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey (step 1),  for step 2 it says "If your app uses only one central or peripheral manager, and that manager exists for the lifetime of your app, there is nothing more you need to do for this step." So step 2 complete? For step 3 I implemented :willRestoreState:, can hardly find modern documentation on this and another person says nothing really needs to be put inside of this? So am I done? Will it just work?

Yes, if you establish your CBCentralManager on app launch and assign the same restore identifier, then your app will be relaunched in response to a long term Bluetooth action (such as a connect) and your delegate method called. You probably don't need any code in the willRestoreState method.  There is no more modern documentation, but that old documentation is still valid.

@Paulw11 Thank you so much it works! One final concern I have, the app only reconnects when the app is terminated by the system (as expected). 1) When I run my app on xcode on my iPhone it is terminated and launched but without reconnecting to BLE I have to force close and reopen to connect. It was able to before. Any way to make it work so I can monitor the console?

You can set up the debugger in Xcode to attach to your process by name and then launch it from the phone or by turning on your peripheral.

Core Bluetooth provides very good support for long-term background operations.  It handles both the case where the app is stopped by iOS while suspended (due to memory or other resource pressure) and where the device itself disconnects for some reason (out of range, power loss etc).
To enable this to work you need to ensure you have opted in to Core Bluetooth state restoration.  This is described in this Apple document - Even though it is an old document, it is still valid.
The general strategy is:

Enable the Core Bluetooth background entitlement in your Xcode project
When you create your CBCentralManager, give it an identifier via CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey
When you get a call to your central manager's didDisconnect delegate method, immediately call connect on the peripheral.
If the peripheral becomes connectable while your app is still running, you will get a call to the didConnect delegate method and you process as usual
If your app has been terminated and the peripheral becomes connectable, iOS will relaunch your app in the background.  Once you have recreated your CBCentralManager with the same restoration identifier, you will get a call to the didConnect delegate method and you process as usual


Thank you it was working sometimes but not others after enabling state restoration but I've since followed these steps more precisely. Previously my method "func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) " had some error handling & at the end a simple self.startScanning(). I've since changed it to call "connectToPreferredPeripheral() ->Bool" instead. Where it includes scanning AND "connectTo(peripheral: preferredPeripheral!.peripheral)" logic. It should work more reliably now right? I've marked your answer correct regardless

Scanning will only help you discover a peripheral you have not seen before. If ther peripheral is known then you just need a connect
